# How can i install divX codec on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, codecs

I have installed Popcorn Time on my laptop but when I try to watch movies it is written that I need to install divX codec.I tried several times but without success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where I can download video codecs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47385/where-i-can-download-video-codecs)

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Try VLC if you haven't - see @mikewhatevers comment on how to get it.

Comment: I have VLC but I don't know how to install divX plugin for it.

Comment: Hello, Can you post a screen capture of the message? have you installed "libavcodec-extra"? Not sure if it is part of the restricted package.